# append lists in dictionary depending on another list python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, append

I have a dictionary like this with empty list as values

```
e = {'joe': [], 'craig': [], 'will' : []}
```

Then with this list below, I want to add the order of the names to the list inside the dictionary corresponding to the key

```
['craig', 'joe', 'will']
```

so the expected output would be

```
{'joe': [2], 'craig': [1], 'will' : [3]}
```

craig came first, joe came second, will came third

Comment: Please don't edit (vandalise) your question out of context of the answers...

Comment: You are blocked from asking because of low quality content. Don't make it worse by vandalising your questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
e = {'joe': [], 'craig': [], 'will' : []}
for i, key in enumerate(['craig', 'joe', 'will'], 1):
    e[key].append(i)

print e
```

---

```
{'will': [3], 'craig': [1], 'joe': [2]}
```

Comment: and if i want to add a second value using another list will it be the same?

Comment: @Codees, yes each key will end up associated with a list of ints

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `list.index()`. See docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

```
e = {'joe': [], 'craig': [], 'will' : []}
names = ['craig', 'joe', 'will']

e['joe'] = names.index('joe')+1
```

Note 1.  You might use `for name in names` if you want to iterate over all names in list.

Note 2.  What do you do if there is a name in your list that is not found as a key in the dictionary?

Note 3.  What do you do if the same names occurs more than once in your list?

Note 4.  Are you sure you want to serialize your list counting from one (1, 2, 3...) and not counting from zero as Python does? (0, 1, 2...).

Comment: `names.index` can be relatively slow if `names` is a large list

Comment: @gnibbler: You're absolutely right. In such a basic question, I preferred to uncover an important method of python lists instead of providing copy-paste-ready optimized code.

Answer (score 0):

```
e = {'joe': [], 'craig': [], 'will' : []}
l = ['craig', 'joe', 'will']
for i,v in enumerate(l, 1):
    e[v].append(i)

print e

>>> 
{'will': [3], 'craig': [1], 'joe': [2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
>>> e = {'joe': [], 'craig': [], 'will' : []}
>>> for i,j in enumerate(['craig', 'joe', 'will']):
...   e[j].append(i+1)
...
>>> e
{'will': [3], 'craig': [1], 'joe': [2]}
```

Or the [index method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) of list:

```
>>> e = {'joe': [], 'craig': [], 'will' : []}
>>> l = ['craig', 'joe', 'will']
>>> for i in l:
...   e[i].append(l.index(i)+1)
...
>>> e
{'will': [3], 'craig': [1], 'joe': [2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use enumerate perhaps?
I will assume you've initialised `e` to the dictionary of empty names. And `namelist` is the list of names in the order you want.

```
for name in e.keys:
  e[name].append(namelist.index[name])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.update`:

```
d = {'joe': [], 'craig': [], 'will' : []}
n = ['craig', 'joe', 'will']
d.update((k, d[k] + [i]) for i, k in enumerate(n, 1))
# {'craig': [1], 'will': [3], 'joe': [2]}
```